# Is there a reason not to uninstall wireless packages if no wireless is present?

Tags: centos, wifi, package-management, iwlwifi

Most of my systems are based on CentOS 7 minimal. This includes by default a number of wireless-related packages:

```
$ yum list installed | grep iw
iw.x86_64                              4.3-1.el7                       @base    
iwl100-firmware.noarch                 39.31.5.1-62.2.el7_5            @updates 
iwl1000-firmware.noarch                1:39.31.5.1-62.2.el7_5          @updates 
iwl105-firmware.noarch                 18.168.6.1-62.2.el7_5           @updates 
iwl135-firmware.noarch                 18.168.6.1-62.2.el7_5           @updates 
iwl2000-firmware.noarch                18.168.6.1-62.2.el7_5           @updates 
iwl2030-firmware.noarch                18.168.6.1-62.2.el7_5           @updates 
iwl3160-firmware.noarch                22.0.7.0-62.2.el7_5             @updates 
iwl3945-firmware.noarch                15.32.2.9-62.2.el7_5            @updates 
iwl4965-firmware.noarch                228.61.2.24-62.2.el7_5          @updates 
iwl5000-firmware.noarch                8.83.5.1_1-62.2.el7_5           @updates 
iwl5150-firmware.noarch                8.24.2.2-62.2.el7_5             @updates 
iwl6000-firmware.noarch                9.221.4.1-62.2.el7_5            @updates 
iwl6000g2a-firmware.noarch             17.168.5.3-62.2.el7_5           @updates 
iwl6000g2b-firmware.noarch             17.168.5.2-62.2.el7_5           @updates 
iwl6050-firmware.noarch                41.28.5.1-62.2.el7_5            @updates 
iwl7260-firmware.noarch                22.0.7.0-62.2.el7_5             @updates 
iwl7265-firmware.noarch                22.0.7.0-62.2.el7_5             @updates
```

I'm using these guest machines on a VM host and they should not ever use wireless.

In general, I'd like to uninstall anything that is not strictly necessary. Before I uninstall them and see what happens, I thought I'd ask here: is there any reason *not* to remove these packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there’s no reason not to uninstall them in a VM. There might be a dependency keeping those packages installed, but if there isn’t, you might as well remove them.